# Getting Google charts to work in Jade

Tags: node.js, express, pug

My Google Chart works fine in this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/6b881at8/5/

In my jade environment and it wasn't working so I outputted the innerHTML of the target chart to my browser's console, and the html of the chart was there.

I converted the html into jade syntax, and manually put it in my jade file and it works fine.

As I need the charts to be dynamic I hope there is a way to get Google Charts working in a Jade environment. I am not sure what is wrong but any help is appreciated!

jade:

```
  .subCategoryContainer
      .subCategoryLabel= subCategory.name 
      .subCategoryLabel 
    .chartWrapper
      .chartContainer
```

charts.js:

```
  google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
  function drawChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Month', 'Foo', 'Bar'],
      ['02/1',  80,      85],
                ['02/8',  20,      35],
      ['02/15',  75,      65],
      ['02/22',  50,      65],
      ['02/28',  60,       50],
    ]);

    var options = {

      hAxis: {title: 'February',  titleTextStyle: {color: '#333'}},
      vAxis: {minValue: 0, title: '% of students'},
      colors:['rgb(32, 170, 188)', 'rgb(32, 188, 77)'],
      lineWidth:4,
      areaOpacity: 0.15,
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.AreaChart(document.querySelector('.chartContainer'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
    console.log(document.querySelector('.chartContainer').innerHTML);
  }
```

console output:

```
charts.js:25 <div style="position: relative;"><div dir="ltr" style="position: relative; width: 400px; height: 200px;"><div style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%;"><svg width="400" height="200" aria-label="A chart." style="overflow: hidden;"><defs id="defs"><clipPath id="_ABSTRACT_RENDERER_ID_0"><rect x="67" y="38" width="267" height="124"></rect></clipPath></defs><rect x="0" y="0" width="400" height="200" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#ffffff"></rect><g><rect x="345" y="38" width="44" height="29" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill-opacity="0" fill="#ffffff"></rect><g><rect x="345" y="38" width="44" height="11" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill-opacity="0" fill="#ffffff"></rect><g><text text-anchor="start" x="371" y="47.35" font-family="Arial" font-size="11" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#222222">Attendance</text></g><rect x="345" y="43.5" width="22" height="5.5" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill-opacity="0.15" fill="#20aabc"></rect><path d="M345,43.5L367,43.5" stroke="#20aabc" stroke-width="4" fill-opacity="1" fill="none"></path></g><g><rect x="345" y="56" width="44" height="11" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill-opacity="0" fill="#ffffff"></rect><g><text text-anchor="start" x="371" y="65.35" font-family="Arial" font-size="11" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#222222">Emotion</text></g><rect x="345" y="61.5" width="22" height="5.5" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill-opacity="0.15" fill="#20bc4d"></rect><path d="M345,61.5L367,61.5" stroke="#20bc4d" stroke-width="4" fill-opacity="1" fill="none"></path></g></g><g><rect x="67" y="38" width="267" height="124" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill-opacity="0" fill="#ffffff"></rect><g clip-path="url(http://localhost:3001/edu/DenverPublicSchools/school/Amesse?type=elementary#_ABSTRACT_RENDERER_ID_0)"><g><rect x="67" y="161" width="267" height="1" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#cccccc"></rect><rect x="67" y="130" width="267" height="1" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#cccccc"></rect><rect x="67" y="100" width="267" height="1" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#cccccc"></rect><rect x="67" y="69" width="267" height="1" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#cccccc"></rect><rect x="67" y="38" width="267" height="1" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#cccccc"></rect></g><g><g><path d="M67.5,161.5L67.5,161.5L67.5,63.099999999999994L134,136.9L200.5,69.25L267,100L333.5,87.7L333.5,161.5L333.5,161.5Z" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill-opacity="0.15" fill="#20aabc"></path></g><g><path d="M67.5,161.5L67.5,161.5L67.5,56.95L134,118.45L200.5,81.55L267,81.55L333.5,100L333.5,161.5L333.5,161.5Z" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill-opacity="0.15" fill="#20bc4d"></path></g></g><g><rect x="67" y="161" width="267" height="1" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#333333"></rect></g><g><path d="M67.5,63.099999999999994L134,136.9L200.5,69.25L267,100L333.5,87.7" stroke="#20aabc" stroke-width="4" fill-opacity="1" fill="none"></path><path d="M67.5,56.95L134,118.45L200.5,81.55L267,81.55L333.5,100" stroke="#20bc4d" stroke-width="4" fill-opacity="1" fill="none"></path></g></g><g></g><g><g><text text-anchor="middle" x="67.5" y="176.68333333333334" font-family="Arial" font-size="11" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#222222">02/1</text></g><g><text text-anchor="middle" x="134" y="176.68333333333334" font-family="Arial" font-size="11" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#222222">02/8</text></g><g><text text-anchor="middle" x="200.5" y="176.68333333333334" font-family="Arial" font-size="11" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#222222">02/15</text></g><g><text text-anchor="middle" x="267" y="176.68333333333334" font-family="Arial" font-size="11" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#222222">02/22</text></g><g><text text-anchor="middle" x="333.5" y="176.68333333333334" font-family="Arial" font-size="11" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#222222">02/28</text></g><g><text text-anchor="end" x="56" y="165.35" font-family="Arial" font-size="11" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#444444">0</text></g><g><text text-anchor="end" x="56" y="134.6" font-family="Arial" font-size="11" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#444444">25</text></g><g><text text-anchor="end" x="56" y="103.85" font-family="Arial" font-size="11" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#444444">50</text></g><g><text text-anchor="end" x="56" y="73.1" font-family="Arial" font-size="11" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#444444">75</text></g><g><text text-anchor="end" x="56" y="42.35" font-family="Arial" font-size="11" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#444444">100</text></g></g></g><g><g><text text-anchor="middle" x="200.5" y="193.01666666666668" font-family="Arial" font-size="11" font-style="italic" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#333333">February</text><rect x="67" y="183.66666666666669" width="267" height="11" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill-opacity="0" fill="#ffffff"></rect></g><g><text text-anchor="middle" x="31.85" y="100" font-family="Arial" font-size="11" font-style="italic" transform="rotate(-90 31.85 100)" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#222222">% of students</text><path d="M22.499999999999996,162L22.500000000000004,38L33.50000000000001,38L33.5,162Z" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill-opacity="0" fill="#ffffff"></path></g></g><g></g></svg></div></div><div aria-hidden="true" style="display: none; position: absolute; top: 210px; left: 410px; white-space: nowrap; font-family: Arial; font-size: 11px;">Emotion</div><div></div></div>
```

Update: when I checked the elements inspector in Chrome I saw that nothing was added to .chartContainer, even though it shows in the console.log. Additionally, using JQuery I am able to edit the inner text of the div element, but not in vanilla js:

```
$('.chartContainer').text('bar1'); //works
document.querySelector('.chartContainer').innerHTML = 'bar2'; //doesn't work
```

from the chrome inspector:

```
<div class="chartWrapper"><div class="chartContainer">bar1</div></div>
```

Comment: Jade is server side and Google Charts is client side, how do you see they need to interact? Can you Explain better _"As I need the charts to be dynamic"_?

Comment: @Sergio - Thanks for looking at this, I haven't done this before but I was imagining that I could pass values in routes: router.get('/:edu_name', function(req, res) {
  array_of_dataPoints = myModule.getXData();

  res.render('./some_route', { array_of_dataPoints, another_array });
});

Comment: How are you calling `/:edu_name`? by ajax, or opening that url with a fresh page?

Comment: @Sergio - opening the url as a fresh page. Currently though (as in the post) I am trying to get it to work with static data. The values are in the charts.js file: var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Month', 'Foo', 'Bar'],
      ['02/1',  80,      85],
                ['02/8',  20,      35],
      ['02/15',  75,      65],
      ['02/22',  50,      65],
      ['02/28',  60,       50],
    ]);

Comment: So you want the data to come from the server? How is your `./some_route` view? You need to pass a object to the render method, `{ array_of_dataPoints, another_array }` needs keys also, but that was maybe just a example attempt. If you are doing a fresh load of the page its not dynamic. So as long as the HTML renders correct, you pass the data to JavaScript somehow and Google loads after the HTML is read by the Browser it should work as in your jsFiddle.

Comment: @Sergio - ah yes, I see what you are referring to, by dynamic I meant that the chart values are not hard coded into the js file once and left alone, the values will be changed either by Ajax or by a page reload (I haven't gotten that far yet, I'm just trying to get the hard coded version working)

Answer (score 0):

The issue was cause because the chart container div was in a loop in my jade template. Once I ensured there was only one div with the class chartContainer, it worked.